# Django prefetch_related multiple queries

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm using **prefetch_related** to join three tables. **Products,** **ProductPrices** and **ProductMeta**. But besides I'm following the documentation, the debugger says that I'm using **three queries** instead of one (with joins)

Also this creates a second problem. **Some products doesn't have prices in some countries** because they are not avaliable there. But using this code, the product appears but with an empty price.

So, **I'd like to exclude the products that doesn't have prices or meta**. I'm doing something wrong?

This is my code:

```
prefetch_prices = Prefetch(
    'product_prices',
    queryset=ProductPrices.objects.filter(country=country_obj),
    to_attr='price_info'
)

prefetch = Prefetch(
    'product_meta',
    queryset=ProductMeta.objects.filter(language=lang),
    to_attr='meta_info'
)

products = Product.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch, prefetch_prices).all()
```

That produces these SQL Queries:

```
{   'sql': 'SELECT DISTINCT `products`.`id`, `products`.`image`, '
               '`products`.`wholesale_price`, `products`.`reference`, '
               '`products`.`ean13`, `products`.`rating`, `products`.`sales`, '
               '`products`.`active`, `products`.`active_in`, '
               '`products`.`encilleria`, `products`.`delivery`, '
               '`products`.`stock`, `products`.`ingredients`, ' 
               'FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`active` = 1 ',
        'time': '0.098'},
    {   'sql': 'SELECT `products_meta`.`id`, `products_meta`.`product_id`, '
               '`products_meta`.`name`, `products_meta`.`slug`, '
               '`products_meta`.`tagline`, `products_meta`.`key_ingredients`, '
               '`products_meta`.`ideal_for`, `products_meta`.`description`, '
               '`products_meta`.`advice`, `products_meta`.`summary`, '
               '`products_meta`.`language` FROM `products_meta` WHERE '
               "(`products_meta`.`language` = 'en' AND "
               '`products_meta`.`product_id` IN (52001, 51972, 52038, 52039, '
               '52040, 52041, 51947, 51948, 51949, 51950, 51951, 51953, 51954, '
               '51832))',
        'time': '0.096'},
    {   'sql': 'SELECT `products_prices`.`id`, `products_prices`.`product_id`, '
               '`products_prices`.`country_id`, `products_prices`.`price` FROM '
               '`products_prices` WHERE (`products_prices`.`country_id` = 1 '
               'AND `products_prices`.`product_id` IN (52001, 51972, 52038, '
               '52039, 52040, 52041, 51947, 51948, 51949, 51950, 51951, 51953, '
               '51954, 51832))',
        'time': '0.046'}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @iklinac said, `prefetch_related` will do multiple queries and marge the results.

But if you want to "exclude the empty rows" or a functionality like INNER JOIN, you could do something like this:

```
a = ProductPrices.objects.filter(country=country_obj)
prefetch1 = Prefetch(
    'product_prices',
    queryset=a,
    to_attr='price_info'
)

b = ProductMeta.objects.filter(language=lang)
prefetch2 = Prefetch(
    'product_meta',
    queryset=b,
    to_attr='meta_info'
)

products = products.prefetch_related(prefetch1, prefetch2)
products = products.filter(id__in=a.values_list('product_id'))
products = products.filter(id__in=b.values_list('product_id'))
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) documentation

> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically retrieve, in a single
>   batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

As you can see from following explanation

> `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
>   relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python.

`prefetch_related` will do queries for each of tables and merge them in python

Additionally if you are having Foreign keys and not Many to Many you could use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) instead

Comment: How can I use select_related? ProductPrices have a Foreign key to Product, but if I'm using Product, how can I do a select_related to ProductPrices?

Comment: @VladislavZhdanov By following documentation should be easy to sort it out, if not post your models

Comment: It appears it's not posible to do this using Product. That's why exist prefetch_related. So that's why I was asking If there is a way to exclude the empty rows using prefetch_related